# Delete ,then Insert Data on table without closing program and run it again

Tags: java, mysql, sql, odbc

I want to insert data on mysql database  directly after delete ,my program check if there is no data on table before insert, i delete data from table ,the program run perfectly and data are deleted, but when I want TO insert ,message apppear tell me that the table contain data !?, it's some thing of cache or handling ,,!!!? , Have you any idea

MY Code :

```
     try {
            String sqll = "Select * from CG1";
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sqll);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            // int c = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                nam = rs.getString(1);

            }
            System.out.println(nam);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    //        
        if (nam == null || Integer.parseInt(nam.toString()) == 0) {
            try {

                //   con.setAutoCommit(false);

                pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into CG1(Exe,Mois,Journal)values(?,?,?)");


                for (int i = 0; i < dtm.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    String exe = dtm.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
                    String mois = dtm.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
                    String journal = dtm.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();


                    pst.setString(1, exe);
                    pst.setString(2, mois);
                    pst.setString(3, journal);

                    pst.addBatch();


                }
                pst.executeBatch();
                //  con.commit();



            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }

        } else {
            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Data EXIST,Would You Like TO DeLETE IT !!", "INFO", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                try {
                    pst = con.prepareStatement("delete * from CG1 ");
                    pst.executeUpdate();


                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }finally{
if(pst!=null){
pst.close();
}
if(rs!=null){
rs.close();
}
if(con!=null){
con.close();
}
}
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "DATA DELETED");

            }

        }


        }catch(Exception e){

        }
```

Comment: may be you have initialize name variable as blank. Just check for blank as well.

Comment: `delete * from CG1` will not do what you think it is doing, but it will throw an error. Remove the `*`, the correct syntax is `delete from CG1`.

Comment: also with your correct syntax,I can't insert after delete ,when I ckeck the database ,data are deleted ,but I should close programand run it again to insert new data  ,have you any idea  ?:!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert data after delete then your insert logic should be in else part after performing delete.

You should have your insert logic in a different method and call it inside if statement when no data is present in DB and also in else statement after performing delete.